# ViewWillDisappear IS called on force close in IOS 10.3 but not IOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I was using **ViewWillDisappear** to determine if a user had left a particular screen and setting a flag.

However, I do not want my code to be called if the app is **force** closed.

The problem is that when force closing it seems as if **ViewWillDisappear** is called in IOS 10.3.1 and 10.3.3 (only on a device not on the simulator)

However, in IOS 11 it is **not** called.

Is this a known issue?

Is there an alternative I could use to determine that the user has left a screen without force closing it?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active
    {
        // app wasn't closed, it's just a common situation when user left the screen
    }
}
```

It works even if screen should be left while app is in the background (i e on asynchronous operation completion), since viewWillDisappear is delayed and called as app becomes active.